# Check and return Boolean when there is substring in string

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am searching only the exact substring from string column and return True/False.

[image]

Row-3,4,5 has the string 'abc' (case-sensitive) but when I tried to get the desired output, it returned TRUE for all rows.
Below is the code I have tried.

```
df['try_output'] = df['String1'].str.contains('ABC',case = False)
```

Is there any modification in the above statement to get the output column '**Required_Output**'.

Comment: Not sure if you're just using 'ABC' as an example but since you have case = False couldn't you just use something like this to return the True/False results that you are seeking? df['try_output'] = df['String1'].str.upper()=='ABC'

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `str.contains` is what you are looking for here, rather, you are looking for an exact match that will not consider upper / lower cases. Therefore, you can simply convert to upper, `str.upper()`, and check whether it equals to 'ABC':

```
df['output'] = df.string_1.str.upper() == 'ABC'

print(df)

  string_1  output
0      ABC    True
1      abc    True
2   XYZabc   False
3   XyzABC   False
4  ABCqqqq   False
5      AbC    True
6      aBC    True
```

---

It's logical why your code returns everything `TRUE` - all of your rows contain 'abc', especially when you specify not to care about upper cases (`case = False`)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.fullmatch`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.fullmatch.html) (`Pandas >= 1.1.0`) without any conversion:

```
df['output'] = df['string_1'].str.fullmatch('abc', case=False)
print(df)

# Output:
  string_1  output
0      ABC    True
1      abc    True
2   XYZabc   False
3   XyzABC   False
4  ABCqqqq   False
5      AbC    True
6      aBC    True
```